# How can I use .htaccess to rewrite a subdomain on a specific file?

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain

I have some experience with .htaccess, and have created straightforward subdomain redirects that work just fine. However, I am stuck on something more complicated for a couple of days now, so I hope to find some help!

I need to re-write the subdomain and the file name too - Here's what I mean:

Whenever the page at en.example.com/entrar is visited, I need it to re-write the url to the correct subdomain: es.example.com/entrar. (The difference is in the language-based subdomains)

So far I have tried this, which is not working:

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^en.example.com/entrar [NC]

RewriteRule (.*) http://es.example.com/entrar [R=301,L]

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^en.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^entrar(.*) http://es.example.com/entrar$1 [R=301,L]
```

The mistake in your attempt was that you were matching the whole URI to `HTTP_HOST`, but `HTTP_HOST` only contains the sub/domain, not the part after it - that's the request URI.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the attempt! I tried this out and it didn't work. Thanks for the explanation about the request uri though, that's very helpful! I wonder if I can set my RewriteCond to only be the request URI.

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, what's the error? And yes, you can match against `%{REQUEST_URI}` if you like in `RewriteCond`.

Comment: Unfortunately there wasn't an error to help me figure this out! I am using Wordpress for this site, so when it can't find the en.example.com/entrar page, it automatically sends me to a 404/search page. I figured .htaccess would be the best way to re-write the URL since that's how I have managed to get it too handle the multiple domain names too... I would like to try matching the REQUEST_URI, I tried "RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)entrar$" but no luck yet.

Comment: Hmm maybe it's interfering with some other rules. I tested it on [htaccess.madewithlove.be](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be) and it seems to work fine :)

Comment: That's a great tool! I tested too and it said both the condition and rule were met. I will keep looking, maybe there are issues with Wordpress loading the search form, perhaps this is overriding the .htaccess.

Comment: Hi Ansari, thank you for that excellent clue, I realized there must be a hierarchy of rules, so I moved my new rule up to the top of my .htaccess and it works!